# Save canvas to lockscreen (WP8 + Cordova)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, wallpaper, lockscreen

I am looking for a solution to save canvas image as WP8 lockscreen background using Cordova/Phonegap? Is it even possible?

I know already that I should add Lockscreen extension to app manifest file:

```
<Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
```

And in html file let's say we have:

```
canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
canvasData=canvas.toDataURL();
```

What then?

Answer (score 0):

Save image in application and then set it as lockscreen image.Try this links. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! But is that possible to do within javascript? Or is there a method to call `LockScreen.SetImageUri` with js?